# Android - Google Map (V2) ignores padding after call to CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds

Tags: android, google-maps

I had used `googleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, desiredHeight);`
to limit the active region of a MapView. Afterwards I need to fit a couple of markers in that active area by using LatLngBounds:

```
    final LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds.builder().include(latlng1).include(latlng2).build();
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0));
```

The problem is that after this call the padding I previously set is completely disregarded and subsequent calls to `googleMap.setPadding` are ignored. Also further attempts to move the camera programmatically don't work. Did anyone encounter this problem before?